# Strange behavior of fsck

Tags: fsck, debian-wheezy

I am using Debian 7 with two HDDs: 500Gb PATA and 750Gb SATA.

blkid shows me the following:

```
root@intel:/etc# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="b6350c6b-5fbd-4e07-9a4b-10b600fbb64c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="2f852e13-38ee-4b56-a474-d675c22d5f28" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="78e34fe3-365c-4c4d-86b8-51615641f9ec" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="data" UUID="03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea" TYPE="ext4"
```

content of fstab:

```
root@intel:/etc# cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2f852e13-38ee-4b56-a474-d675c22d5f28    /               ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=78e34fe3-365c-4c4d-86b8-51615641f9ec    /home           ext4    defaults       0       2
# /data was on /dev/sdb1
UUID=b6350c6b-5fbd-4e07-9a4b-10b600fbb64c    /data       ext4    defaults       0   2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea    none            swap    sw         0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

System can't boot until I comment out `/dev/sdb1`. The `fsck` fails to check filesystem:

```
root@intel:/etc# fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.swap: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.swap for /dev/sdb1
```

but after boot with commented

```
# /data was on /dev/sdb1
UUID=b6350c6b-5fbd-4e07-9a4b-10b600fbb64c    /data       ext4    defaults       0   2
```

line of `fstab` I can mount /dev/sdb1.

The only one question is "What's happening?". Is my 750Gb HDD dying? How can I check /dev/sdb1?

Best regards.

Comment: When you say that after boot you can mount `/dev/sdb1`, could you tell us **exactly** what command you're using to mount it?

Comment: `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blkid shows that /dev/sdb1 is an ext4 filesystem (and by you trying to mount it, suggests it is) however, your fstab disagrees:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea    none            swap    sw         0       0
```

And your UUID matches /dev/sdb1 as you showed with blkid:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="data" UUID="03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea" TYPE="ext4"
```

During boot, it is trying to use /dev/sdb1 as it's swap partition and does an fsck.swap /dev/sdb1 which fails since it's not a swap partition.

You should be able to fsck it with `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1` and you'll need to edit your fstab to reflect the REAL swap parition's uuid.

It appears you just have your two UUIDs switched around:

```
UUID=b6350c6b-5fbd-4e07-9a4b-10b600fbb64c    /data       ext4    defaults       0   2
UUID=03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea    none            swap    sw         0       0
```

vs

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="b6350c6b-5fbd-4e07-9a4b-10b600fbb64c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="03c3f01f-d390-49de-a570-3de4b73a9fea" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Yep. I found it too just after writing a question. But I don't know why it's happened. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your partition table with cfdisk or similar tool. Chances are the partition type of /dev/sdb1 is set to "Linux swap" instead of "Linux".

In order to check the partition directly, call `e4fsck /dev/sdb1`.